# Como declarar un array u obejto en js?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

estoy trabajando en JS, para lo que estoy haciendo ocupo un arreglo u objeto la verdad no estoy seguro que pueda almacenar varios registro por darle un ejemplo:

arr[0].name = "Angel"

arr[0].age = 19

arr[0].kg = 70

arr[1].name = "Luis"

arr[1].age = 22

arr[1].kg = 75

Ya que ocupo meter toda esa información en una sola variable para poder construir una tabla que quiero, pero no encuentro la forma en JS de hacerla.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más claro? Por lo que entiendo quieres un arreglo de objetos.

Comment: Si, quiero un arreglo que pueda recorrer por su indice y que cada indice tenga varias variables, de esta forma pudiera tener por ejemplo un arreglo de personas donde cada indice es una persona diferente pero al final todo estaría en el mismo arreglo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tú puedes meter varios objetos en un array. La clave de todo en Javascript es usar `[]` para array y usar `{}` para objeto.

Por ejemplo aquí:

```
var allPeople = [
    {name:"Angel", age: 19, kg:70},
    {name:"Luis", age: 22, kg:75},
];
```

`allPeople` es un array, y dentro tiene varios objetos: `{}`.

Veamos una prueba y su recorrido:

```js
var allPeople = [
    {name:"Angel", age: 19, kg:70},
    {name:"Luis", age: 22, kg:75},
];

allPeople.forEach(function(obj, index){
    for (var key in obj){
        console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
    }
});
```

Supongamos que quieres modificar el array una vez creado, pues le puedes agregar otros objetos usando `push`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var allPeople = [
    {name:"Angel", age: 19, kg:70},
    {name:"Luis", age: 22, kg:75},
];


allPeople.push({name:"Marta", age: 20, kg:65});

allPeople.forEach(function(obj, index){
    for (var key in obj){
        console.log(`${key}: ${obj[key]}`);
    }
});
```

Para más detalles consulta la documentación:

- [Sobre los arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [Sobre los objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

Un array es básicamente una lista, un conjunto de elementos cuyos items se separan por una coma (puede contener objetos y no es necesario que todos sus elementos sean del mismo tipo), para acceder a sus elementos se hace por la posición, iniciando por 0, accediendo entonces el primer elemento de la siguiente manera **nombreArray[0]**, si se desea acceder a otro elemento del array solo se debe indicar el índice correspondiente.

Un objeto tiene una estructura de pares clave/valor, cada par se separa por una coma.
Para acceder al valor  que le corresponde a una propiedad una forma de lograrlo es la siguiente manera **nombreObjeto.nombrePropiedad** (ej. persona.name)

Ejemplo de arrays:

```
[1,4,5,6,]
["Rojo","Blanco","Negro","Azul","Gris"]
```

Ejemplo de objeto:

```
{
name: "Angel",
age: 19,
kg: 70,
name: "Luis",
age: 22
}
```

Entonces se podría hacer algo así:

```
const personas [
  {
    name: "Angel",
    age: 19,
    kg: 70,
  },
  {
    name: "Pedro",
    age: 34,
    kg: 75,
  },
  {
    name: "Julia",
    age: 33,
    kg: 62,
  },
];
```

Y para acceder a cada uno se podría hacer:
console.log(personas[0].name) //Devolvería "Angel"
console.log(personas[1].name) //Devolvería "Pedro"
console.log(personas[2].kg) //Devolvería 62

También sería posible utilizar un loop para recorrer el array y por cada elemento hacer algo, ej:

```
for(const persona of personas) {
console.log(persona.name)
}
```